# С# Dapper Mapping Error

Tags: c#, oracle, mapping, dapper

In my asp.net project I use dapper for getting data from an Oracle database.
I have an sql request like this:

```
select SUM(( pt.end_date - pt.start_date ) * 24 ) time_coacsh                                           
      ,SUM(( pt.end_date - pt.start_date ) * 24 )/COUNT(rc.reg_coach_id) oborot_coacsh 
from ...
```

and a model with only these properties:

```
[Column("time_coacsh")]
public Double TimeCoacsh { get; set; }

[Column("oborot_coacsh")]
public Double OborotCoacsh { get; set; }
```

I am trying to get a list of objects through the following method:

```
public IEnumerable<TModel> Query<TModel>(string sql, object paramsSql = null)
{
    SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(TModel), new CustomPropertyTypeMap(typeof(TModel), BaseParamMappings.SelectProperty));

    return SqlMapper.Query<TModel>(_db, new CommandDefinition(sql, paramsSql, null, null, CommandType.Text)).ToList();
}
```

However I get this error:

> Error parsing column 0 (TIME_COACSH=null)

If I execute the sql request in oracle I will get needed data without some `null` values.

In the model I tried to use Float, Decimal, Double, but I get the same error.

Comment: Try making the field nullable: `public Double? TimeCoacsh`

Comment: I tried `Double?` and `float?`. Nothing changed

Comment: Is a large amount of data returned?

Comment: @SteveJ, no. I tested with request, which return only 15 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

fields `time_coacsh` and `oborot_coacsh` were equal to values like `13,333333333333333333333333333338` that is, they had about 40 decimal places.
i changed sql request to

```
select round( SUM( ( pt.end_date - pt.start_date ) * 24 ),2 ) time_coacsh                                           
      ,round (SUM( ( pt.end_date - pt.start_date ) * 24 )/COUNT( rc.reg_coach_id ), 2)  oborot_coacsh
```

and in model use `Decimal` type for these fields

PS: Dapper support `Column` attribute

Comment: Ah cool. Glad you sorted it. I'll delete my answer so as not to mislead anyone about the attribute.